# Issue sorting by date with lodash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I'm trying to have a sorted list of items by data using lodash and vue moments, I'm using a computed property but for some reason this computed property named sortByUsedDate returns a number instead of a sorted array... it's returning 11 exactly.

This is my code:

```
sortByUsedDate: function(){

        let sortedCodes = _.orderBy(this.modalPayload.discountcodes, (code) => {
            return Vue.moment(code.usedDate).format('MDYYYY');
        }, ['desc']);

        let sortedWithoutUnused = _.remove(sortedCodes, function(code) {
            return code.isBought === 1;
        });

        let unusedCodes = _.filter(this.modalPayload.discountcodes, function(code){
            return code.isBought == 0;
        });

        let final = sortedWithoutUnused.push(unusedCodes);

        return final;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the length of the array. You should just return the array without the assignment:

```
sortedWithoutUnused.push(unusedCodes);

return sortedWithoutUnused;
```

But if you're trying to combine two arrays, I don't think you want to use push anyway, you'll probably want to use `...` or `.concat` instead:

```
return [...sortedWithoutUnused, ...unusedCodes];
```

Or

```
return sortedWithoutUnused.concat(unusedCodes);
```

Comment: Or use `Array#slice` instead

Comment: Or use [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) like this: `return [...sortedWithoutUnused, ... unusedCodes]`